# Application of the mean value theorem to $f(x)=x^{-s}$ (Prop 2.5 in Princeton Lectures in Analysis-Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

The proof of the following proposition in the book

[image]

says that
[image]
But I don't quite understand why this is true. Are we using MVT in the Real sense?
As far as I am aware of, applying MVT to $f(x)=x^{-s}$, with the interval $n\leq x\leq n+1$, we get
$$
\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{n+1-n}=f'(c)\\
$$
that is
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)^s} - \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{-s}{c^{s+1}}
$$
$$
\text{where } c\in[n,n+1]
$$
How does this lead to the inequality? Or is this now not true anymore because we are in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You have to take absolute values on both sides after the last step that you wrote. Also, for what value of $c \in [ n, n + 1 ]$ is the right side the largest? That will be an upper bound for the left side.

Comment: Thank you very much Singhal. I get it now. Sometimes I just feel I need to do more than just saying thank you. But really, thank you.